# How to get member object from Id discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a user's id however I want to be able to convert this into a member object.
my bot has a leader board and stores uses the users discord id as a key. I want to be able to use these id's to get a member object. I want to be able to access this even if that user is not in the server.
Is this possible, if so how can I do it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line of code:

```py
member_obj = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
```

So for example, this is how you could use it in a function:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def id_to_name(ctx, *, id):
    member_obj = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
    await ctx.send(f'ID to name: {member_obj.display_name}')
```

Comment: When i use this it always returns
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'get_member'

Comment: @noahatholm Try doing `ctx.guild.get_member()` instead or `ctx.get_member()`.

Comment: `ctx.guild.get_members()` worked however it is returning  `none` do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: If you're trying to print a discord item, it's normal for it to return none. You need to use it as a *method* like: `member_obj.mention` or something like that. Always remember that discord objects aren't strings or integers.

Answer (score -1):

You could do either of two things.

**If you want to use ctx:**

```
ctx.author.mention
```

#If you want to use the member thing.

```
@Bot.command()

async def example(ctx, member : discord.Member):

       await ctx.send(f"name{member.mention or ctx.authour.mention}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. They were asking how to get the Member object from an ID in Discord.py, not how to mention a user.