# discord.py rewrite: is there a way to get the username of multiple ids which are inside a json file (no mention)?

Tags: json, discord.py

its me again. so, yesterday i was able to read out my id's. now i removed the `[]` with a string. Now, where i am able, to read out the IDs without the ugly ass `[]` with are just annoying lol, getting the Users dont work. even if there is just one ID in the json file. so, i'll ask here if anyone knows how i can get the usernames of the IDs inside the json file. Here is my code so far, under the code is my json file.

```
@commands.command(name='checkblock')  # checks if a user is on the list of blocked users
    async def checkblock(self, ctx):
        with open('bot_config/blocked_users.json') as file:
            json_dict = json.load(file)
            list1 = json_dict["blockedUser"]
            list_string = str(list1)[1:-1]
            user_name = self.bot.get_user(list_string)

        template = '**Name: {}**\nID: {}\n'
        member_list = '\n' .join([template.format(user_name, list_string) for json_dict["blockedUser"] in json_dict])
        await ctx.send('Following users are currently blocked:\n'
                       f'{member_list}')
```

and here my json file:

```
{
    "blockedUser": [
        805047615128469534,
        360881524410810380,
        235148962103951360
    ]
}
```

and here is what my Bot sends in the channel.
[Click here, i dont know how to add images. :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQo83.png)

Comment: Please take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-get-a-specific-model), instead of making a question that was definitely asked too many times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get member object from Id discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331654/how-to-get-member-object-from-id-discord-py)